# How do I get the balance of an account in Ethereum?

Tags: ethereum

How can I programmatically discover how much ETH is in a given account on the Ethereum blockchain?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**On the Web:**

(Not programmatic, but for completeness...) If you just want to get the balance of an account or contract, you can visit http://etherchain.org or http://etherscan.io.

**From the geth, eth, pyeth consoles:**

Using the Javascript API, (which is what the geth, eth and pyeth consoles use), you can get the balance of an account with the following:

```
web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase));
```

"web3" is the [Ethereum-compatible Javascript library web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API).

"eth" is actually a shorthand for "web3.eth" (automatically available in geth). So, really, the above should be written:

```
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.coinbase));
```

"web3.eth.coinbase" is the default account for your console session. You can plug in other values for it, if you like. All account balances are open in Ethereum. Ex, if you have multiple accounts:

```
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0]));
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[1]));
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[2]));
```

or

```
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance('0x2910543af39aba0cd09dbb2d50200b3e800a63d2'));
```

EDIT: Here's a handy script for listing the balances of all of your accounts:

```
function checkAllBalances() { var i =0; eth.accounts.forEach( function(e){ console.log("  eth.accounts["+i+"]: " +  e + " \tbalance: " + web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(e), "ether") + " ether"); i++; })}; checkAllBalances();
```

**Inside Contracts:**

Inside contracts, Solidity provides a simple way to get balances. Every address has a .balance property, which returns the value in wei. Sample contract:

```
contract ownerbalancereturner {

    address owner;

    function ownerbalancereturner() public {
        owner = msg.sender; 
    }

    function getOwnerBalance() constant returns (uint) {
        return owner.balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I recommend that your script for listing balances can be much simpler:

eth.accounts.forEach( function(e, i){ console.log("  eth.accounts["+i+"]: " +  e + " \tbalance: " + web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(e), "ether") + " ether") })

Comment: eth.getBalance() receives 2 parameters, not 1, what happens when you only supply one? what's the default for the second one?

Comment: web3.fromWei is not a function

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#getbalance), (check out the link for variations)

```
web3.eth.getBalance("0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1")
.then(console.log);
> "1000000000000"
```

Answer (score 2):

For the new release of the web3 API:

The latest version of **web3** API (vers. **beta 1.xx**) uses promises (asynchronous, like callback).
Dokumentation: [web3 beta 1.xx](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#id33)

Hence it is a Promise and returns String for the given address in wei.

I am on **Linux** (openSUSE), **geth** 1.7.3, **Rinkeby Ethereum testnet**, using **Meteor 1.6.1**, and got it to work the following way connecting via **IPC Provider** to my geth node:

```
// serverside js file

import Web3 from 'web3';

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  var net = require('net');
  var web3 = new Web3('/home/xxYourHomeFolderxx/.ethereum/geth.ipc', net);
};

  // set the default account
  web3.eth.defaultAccount = '0x123..............';

  web3.eth.coinbase = '0x123..............';

  web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, acc) {
    _.each(acc, function(e) {
      web3.eth.getBalance(e, function (error, result) {
        if (!error) {
          console.log(e + ': ' + result);
        };
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: those using nodejs (I'm on v11.5.0) won't make this work because `import` isn't supported.  so you'll need to do `const Web3 = require('web3');` instead

Comment: also, the balance will be returned in wei to it needs to be converted with `.fromWei()`

Answer (score 1):

**Ethers.js**

Using the Ethers.js JavaScript library, you can get an account's balance with [provider.getBalance()](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getBalance).

Here's a simple example (using Infura node or similar):

```js
const provider =
    new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/<your_id>');

async function checkBalance() {
    balance = await provider.getBalance('0x2910543af39aba0cd09dbb2d50200b3e800a63d2');
    console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(balance));
}

checkBalance();
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'for-each' loop works, but also a very short and simple way to get the balance is simply adding the **await** for the function:

```
var bal = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
```

or if you want to display it directly:

```
console.log('balance = : ', await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]));
```

Comment: when i run this i get Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function